# Destructuring works in OSX, fails on Linux

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, ecmascript-6

I am using some of the ES6 feature set in some Mocha tests I've created and included that are a few destructuring statements. Here's an example:

```
const {logger, saveProxy, resolved, msg} = helpers;
```

I run these test script from OSX most of the time and it works like a charm. But because the nodejs service utilizes some Unix-only binaries I do need to test in Linux too. No problem I switch over to Linux with a Vagrant VM and point to precisely the same test script and get the following error stack:

```
const {logger, saveProxy, resolved, msg} = helpers; 
      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:216:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:213:14)
    at Mocha.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:453:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:393:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:430:10)
    at startup (node.js:141:18)
    at node.js:1003:3
```

In both Linux and OSX I'm running node version `5.4.0` so destructuring should NOT be an issue. I'm at my wits end, can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destructuring is still work in progress in node.js, and can be enabled with the `--harmony_destructuring` flag.

You're probably running your script differently in the two environments. Which flags are you passing to the node runtime?

You can see a list of supported ES2015 features by running:

```
node --v8-options | grep harmony
```

There you'll see which ones are "in progress", which means they're disabled by default.

Comment: Interesting, I had thought that node 5.x supported destructing. Any idea why it works on OSX but not Linux? Note: the harmony settings on both appear to be the same.

Comment: Like I said, I'd look into how you're invoking node. Do you do it directly through the command line? Can you make sure it's not an alias or a symlink to a script that adds some sugar on top of the node executable?

Comment: it's precisely the same; done via command line or via gulp task

Comment: @ken: well, what does the gulp task do?

Comment: same thing as the command line: `mocha test/integration/3.\ verify.js` ... fairly certain this is a dead end. Execution is started the same way. No switches, flags, or ENV variables. In the case of gulp, it "watches" for a changed file and then runs this (or whatever file changed).